# IMemoryCache removes old data when new data is set?

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core, memory

I'd like to be able to cache a List of products.
And if I get a new List of products, which contains new products, I'd like to add them to the cached products.
And if the new list of products also contains an updated product which is already cached, I'd like the cached product to be updated with a new copy.

I tried to accomplish this by creating 2 different methods: 1 that sets the cached items, and one that gets the cached items.

```
        public async Task<T> CreateOrUpdate<T>(string cacheKey, T entityToAdd, int cacheExpirationMinutes = 5)
        {
                _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, entityToAdd, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheExpirationMinutes));
                return default(T);
        }
```

```
// I have an emptyItem here because cacheservice methods don't seem to accept less than 3 parameters 
       public async Task<T> TryGetFromCache<T>(string cacheKey, T emptyItem, int cacheExpirationMinutes = 5)
        {
            var cachedItem = _memoryCache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
            return cachedItem;
        }
```

_memoryCache is just that I've added IMemoryCache through dependency injection.

this is how I invoke the methods in a ProductHandler:

```
//products is a list of products which I get from db
 await _cacheService.CreateOrUpdate(CacheKey.ProductList, products, minutesToMidnight);

var emptyList = new List<Product>();
cachedOrders = await _cacheService.TryGetFromCache(CacheKey.ProductList, emptyList, minutesToMidnight);
```

and the CacheKey is:

```
    public static class CacheKey
    {
        public static string ProductList => "ProductList";
    }
```

However, what happens in this scenario, is that when I first set all the products, and then get all the products, everything is seemingly fine.
But then when I invoke it to set new products again, it seems to completely wipe out what was there beforehand, and sets the new products. So when I get the cached products again, only the products from the second iteration are cached and that's all I get back.

How would one then establish what I'm aiming for?

Comment: If you need to keep track of the products individually, you need to cache them individually - and not as a list. Either that, or you need to get the cached list, update the list as you see fit and recache it

Comment: @Xerillio if I'd go for the first option, would every product need its own cacheKey then?

Comment: Yes. Usually you'd use it's ID if it has such a property. Something like `$"Product_{product.Id}"`